# How to add a timepicker field in my rails 4 app?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I add a timepicker field in my rails app?

I am using this [addon](https://github.com/ywjno/bootstrap-timepicker-rails-addon)

As directed in the documentation, I first included this in my gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-timepicker-rails-addon'
```

Then, I ran bundle install and included the bootstrap-timepicker in my JS and CSS files, so that my app/assets/javascripts/application.js looks like:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require_tree .
```

and my app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss looks like:

```
 *
 *= require bootstrap-timepicker
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

Finally in my views, I included this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#timepicker').timepicker();
  });
</script>
```

and the following in one of my form fields:

```
  <div class="field">
     <%= label_tag ("Time of Travel ") %><br>
     <%= text_field_tag :dot, nil, :id => "timepicker" %>
  </div>
```

After all this, I still am not able to get my form properly display the time field. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Any other alternative is also welcome!

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: no...none whatsoever

Comment: In browser console run this `$('#timepicker').timepicker();` and see

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not a function error shown

Comment: You need to include bootstrap too for it to work. [Check this example](https://github.com/ywjno/bootstrap-timepicker-rails-addon/tree/master/testapp/rails3/app) and see how they have included things in files you have mentioned. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the bootstrap added in my gemfile: gem 'bootstrap-sass'

Comment: See application.js in the link I gave you and compare.

Comment: You can checkout [Pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time.htm) . It is independent of bootstrap and depends only on jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Bootstrap in your rails app? 
This addon is an extra addon for Bootstrap users.

It seems that this gem supports only Bootstrap 2.x, if you're using Bootstrap 3, I recommend using this addon instead(I don't know if there's a gem of this, but you can always use the downloaded source):
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [bootstrap-timepicker-rails gem](https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails)  or [jquery-timepicker-rails gem](https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-timepicker-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you got the problem solved. Anyway, I followed the instruction from the [website](https://github.com/ywjno/bootstrap-timepicker-rails-addon) and it seems working fine for me. Maybe you should check whether you have the right Bootstrap version installed and there's no compatibility issue with different versions of Bootstrap. Also check whether you are calling the right #id.